# Ruby on Rails tutorial errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am doing a Rails tutorial for a blog and I am getting 2 errors. When you generate the new site in order to have the pages show up you need to change 'application' to 'default' under the layout. That works fine but I believe it is creating a new error and it won't run the 'destroy' .js action. Instead, when you go to delete the post it uses a 'get' method and just links to the posts page (no deleting it).

**Here is the error: (if you notice it goes to default.js)**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"
):
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in
`call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `
call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in t
agged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'

rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middlewa
re.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in
start_thread'


Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5
.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5
.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5
.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5
.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.e
rb (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5
.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb withi
n rescues/layout (1341.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inline
d_string (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_s
tring (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (922.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.
0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (2106.0ms)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to either get the pages to show up using the 'application' instead of 'default' which looks like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

or how to get the js to execute correctly.

Comment: Why did you rename the application to default? Did you also change application.js into default.js in app/assets/javascripts ?

Comment: I am now starting to realize the root of the issue is that I am using WIndows 7 64 bit. I apparently have to change some code and install gem files to get it working properly, although I am still looking for clear guidance on that aspect. So, 64 doesn't use the files the same way it does with 32

Comment: On http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, the side bar states "The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language."